# How to fix "Function or Variable is not defined" error when variable is defined and used previously in Matlab?

Tags: image, matlab

The code is supposed to look through a certain folder for any subfolders. Then within each subfolder it is supposed to look for every image and average them all together. It then saves that averaged image into a separate folder and repeats for all remaining subfolders.

You can directly test this code by copy and pasting into your own MatLab program and changing the directories given, there are no dependencies.

My Problem:The variable 'sumImage' is catching an error at the very end of the for loop.

```
finImage = uint8(sumImage / numberOfImages);
```

Even though sumImage is used frequently throughout the previous code with no errors.

I assumed it was a snag with the for loops within each other however, the first time I ran the program it ran mostly flawlessly. However, further attempts to run the code have resulted in the compiler error seen. I've tried changing the variable name and even declaring it as a double at the beginning to no avail.

```
folder1 = dir('C:\Users\slenka\Desktop\Image_Analysis\Original');
numberOfFolders = length(folder1);

for z = 1 : numberOfFolders
    currD = folder1(z).name;
    cd(currD);
    imageFiles = [dir(fullfile(currD,'*.TIF'));         dir(fullfile(currD,'*.PNG')); dir(fullfile(currD,'*.BMP'));     dir(fullfile(currD,'*.jpg'))];
    numberOfImages = length(imageFiles);

    for k = 1 : numberOfImages
    fullFileName = fullfile(currD, imageFiles(k).name);
    fprintf('About to read %s\n', fullFileName);
    thisImage=imread(fullFileName);
    [thisRows, thisColumns, thisNumberOfColorChannels] = size(thisImage);
    if k == 1
        % Save the first image.
        sumImage = double(thisImage);
        % Save its dimensions so we can match later images' sizes to this first one.
        rows1 = thisRows;
        columns1 = thisColumns;
        numberOfColorChannels1 = thisNumberOfColorChannels;
        theyreColorImages = numberOfColorChannels1 >= 3;
    else
        % It's the second, or later, image.
        if rows1 ~= thisRows || columns1 ~= thisColumns
            % It's not the same size, so resize it to the size of the first image.
            thisImage = imresize(thisImage, [rows1, columns1]);
        end
        % Make sure the colors match - either all color or all gray scale, according to the first one.
        if thisNumberOfColorChannels == 3 && numberOfColorChannels1 == 1
            % We have color.  Need to change it to grayscale to match the first one.
            thisImage = rgb2gray(thisImage);
            theyreColorImages = false;
        elseif thisNumberOfColorChannels == 1 && numberOfColorChannels1 == 3
            % We have grayscale.  Need to change it to RGB to match the first one.
            thisImage = cat(3, thisImage, thisImage, thisImage);
            theyreColorImages = true;
        end
        % Now do the summation.
        sumImage = sumImage + double(thisImage); % Be sure to cast to double to prevent clipping.   [rows, columns, numberOfColorBands]=size(thisImage);

        % It can't display an RGB image if it's floating point and more than 255.
        % So divide it by the number of images to get it into the 0-255 range.
        if theyreColorImages
            displayedImage = uint8(sumImage / k);
        else
            displayedImage = sumImage;
        end
        imshow(displayedImage, []);
        drawnow;
    end
    end


%--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Compute and display the final image:
finImage = uint8(sumImage / numberOfImages);
baseFileName = sprintf('Image #%d.png', z);
fullFileName =     fullfile('C:\Users\slenka\Desktop\Image_Analysis\Averaged', baseFileName);
imwrite(finImage, fullFileName);
    end
```

Expected results: An  output folder with an averaged image for each folder (10 folders total) accessed by the program

Actual results: A compiler error and two distorted images in the output folder

Edit: I got it working due to the comments, however now that it is working it averages all images on my desktop instead. Any ideas? I only want it to average images in the specific folder.

Comment: Hint: What happens if `numberOfImages` is 0 in the first iteration of the loop?

Comment: Wellcome to stackoveflow!

It is complicated to answer this without knowing your directory structure. In the case that `numberOfFolders` is `0` or `numberOfImages` is `0` every time, `sumImage` might never be set. I'd suggest making a copy of your script, remove everything which does not deal with reading filenames or `sumImage`, and then use the [debugger](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html) to investigate your code.

Comment: I never thought to think of that, thank you!

Comment: After your edit: we cannot tell why the fixed code doesn’t do what you want, because the fixed code is only on your machine, not in the question.